# Issue with parsing JSON flat file in PhantomJS (NO jquery, raw javascript please)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, phantomjs, commonjs

So here is the issue. I have a straight export from mongodb collection as json flat file. I am trying to get my phantomjs app to read and parse the flat file from MongoDB and convert it into an object for phantomjs to parse. For some reason I cannot parse the JSON string normally.

(note: NO jQuery solutions. This needs to be raw javascript)

Here is my flat file from mongodb. It seems fine:

```
    { "host" : "www.myfoxphilly.com", "path" : "/category/233430/entertainment", "created_at" : { "$date" : 1375199393295 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "51f7e0a1dc12a13510000002" } }{ "host" : "www.news9.com", "path" : "/category/112032/news", "created_at" : { "$date" : 1375285798173 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "51f9322668ee1e660c000001" } }{ "host" : "www.myfoxphilly.com", "path" : "/category/233430/entertainment", "created_at" : { "$date" : 1375285823602 }, "_id" : { "$oid" : "51f9323f68ee1e660c000002" } }
```

Here is the config file that is attempting to parse the above JSON flat file

```
var fs = require('fs');
var data = fs.read('configData.json');
var newdata =  JSON.stringify(data);
var dataobj = eval("["+newdata+"]");
console.log(typeof(newdata));

exports.tests = dataobj;

// Sample object (works fine like this):[{path:'/category/112043/sports' ,host:'www.newson6.com'}];

exports.getFileName = function(test,local) {
return 'results/' + test.host.replace(/\./g,'-').replace(/\:[0-9]+/,'').replace('-com','').replace('www-','') + test.path.replace(/\//g,'-').replace(/\?clienttype=/g, "clienttype") + ((local) ? '-locl' : '-prod')
}
```

So when I run phantom, I get no data. That JSON becomes one single object, instead of the object example I have in the comment section.

If I just replace the JS common library flat file import and make "data" a string, it works just fine, like so:

```
var data = '{"host" : "www.myfoxphilly.com", "path" : "/some/path/233409"}';
```

Is there some sort of issue going on with the js common library file import when I import the JSON in as a string? Help please.

ONCE AGAIN, no jQuery, I will down vote you without looking. I <3 jQuery, but you guys need to realize when it's appropriate to use (i.e. browser-based js).

Comment: `eval`? You use `JSON.stringify`, but not `JSON.parse`? Also, note that the flat file content you provided is not valid JSON.

Comment: You are right about the JSON. I ran it through json lint and got an error ... is this a mongo error... this is straight "mongoexport" ... so it should be valid hmm.... I'm gonna ignore the eval comment until you can provide a non-eval answer, which means no JSON.parse or stringify as those use eval and no json2 as that is lame. (good luck dbag :P)

Comment: "note: NO jQuery solutions. This needs to be raw javascript" -- how come?

Comment: There's a reason why everyone recommends using `JSON.parse` or a shim instead of `eval`.

Comment: @Jan ... this is non-browser js. Ideally, I think its better practice to avoid using jquery in nodejs and commonjs apps. Also, I find that too many people lean on jQuery and really have no foundation in javascript. That's a problem.

Comment: @DCoder ... yes yes yes 'Eval is Evil' ... *yawn* ... we've all read Crockford a couple of times. This is a non-public app, getting data from a closed and secure source. Eval is still a part of the spec for a reason. But really I just threw that in to raise hackles. I'll probably do a double JSON.parse (BUT even that uses *gasp* eval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG! You used `eval` ... :P I'm suprised this question hasn't already been down voted 5 times.

On the real, excellent question.

Your problem, if @DCoder has actually posted an answer, is your JSON. A 'flat file from mongodb' is not necessarily valid JSON. Further, to make it valid you're gonna need to parse the string first:

1. wrap it in square braces
2. make sure you have a comma after each data line exported from mongo.
3. Seriously, `eval`? Use JSON.parse twice on your converted string.

That should solve it. Everything else looks clean.

(.. `eval` .. I cant believe this scrub)

Comment: You guys leave me alone about eval! But thanks, cliffbarnes, that was the issue.

Comment: Dislike for spending more time chastising the use of 'eval' rather then hinting at why it would be bad.  I'm also confused on why JSON.parse would need to be run twice